# Calculate Proportions of the Duplicate IDs using R

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWM96.png)

BLOCK ID10

180050110003088, 180050110003088, 180050110001057, 
180050110001057, 180050111001053, 180050111001053, 180050115002189, 
180050115002189, 180050105001012, 180050105001012, 180050111006001, 
180050111006001, 180050111006001, 180050111006001, 180050115002017, 
180050115002017, 180050102001023, 180050102001023, 180050102001024, 
180050102001024, 180050102004129, 180050102004129, 180050102001008, 
180050102001008, 180050113001051, 180050113001051, 180050106003001, 
180050106003001, 180050115004073, 180050115004073, 180050108004013, 
180050108004013, 180050101001132, 180050101001132, 180050110001053, 
180050110001053, 180050110001115, 180050110001115, 180050101004075

Shape Area

20.584551, 44.661716, 11.715119, 8.264571, 17.644236, 
    4.224248, 1.967708, 3.471188, 4.873869, 3.419209, 34.785751, 
    2.189894, 7.286233, 1.428156, 9.943958, 4.755272, 1.447128, 
    1.731923, 1.447128, 1.731923, 5.348266, 1.447128, 1.447128, 
    1.731923, 4.873869, 3.419209, 3.419209, 1.788985, 23.476536, 
    15.001075, 5.348266, 9.943958, 1.447128, 1.731923, 17.644236, 
    8.264571, 4.484065, 1.731923, 9.943958

to understand the data in more detail please click on the image link

I have a data frame that has BLOCKID10 field with duplicated values but their SHape Areas are different. What I am trying to do is to sum the areas of duplicate values and divide the sum with their individual value(basically calculating proportion) and then populating the proportion in a new column. Some of the values are not repeating, so the proportion for them would be 1.

How should I solve this?

I tried dplyr and other methods but they are generating an error. Used nested for loops but it is taking lot of time as number of total runs goes above 1.3 billion.

Comment: please use `dput` to post your data in reproducible form. Do not use images.

Comment: Consider `ave`: `df$prop <- with(df, Shape_Area / ave(Shape_Area, BLOCKID10, FUN=sum))`

Comment: @Parfait would it sum the areas then take an average of that area? So for two same IDS: (area1 +area2) / 2 ?